# Android Google Places autocomplete needs extra request to get coordinates

Tags: android, google-places-api

Is it possible to get the coordinates for the returned locations from Google Places autocomplete in the same request, instead of having to make an extra request for place details?

Comment: No, unless if you are using Details of Places API instead of Autocomplete, but quickly you will be over your quota limit.

Comment: If I ask for a place details everytime the user chooses a location I will be over my quota limit too. Or not?

Comment: It's true. But not lesser time frame than using Places-search/Details as autocomplete source.